# How can I make the [Authorize] attribute more flexible?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, authorize-attribute

I have an MVC 5 application that I lock down by only allowing certain authenticated users to have access to specific actions within my controller.  I utilize the authorize attribute at the top of the class allowing only the user(s) I want to gain access after login.  I do this with the following attribute placed at top of my class...

```
[Authorize(Users="user1,user2")]
```

This works great!  However, what if I don't want to recompile and deploy the application everytime I want to add a new user to this specific controller?

I thought I might add this in my web.config file under  as a key like so...

```
<appSettings>
  <add users="user1,user2"/>
</appSettings>
```

But when I try to access this key in my controller like so: [Authorize(Users=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["users"])] I am getting an error: Cannot resolve symbol 'AppSettings'.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why an answer that didn't *answer* the question was accepted.  Regardless, I thought it might be worth adding an answer for any future travelers.

While this functionality isn't provided out of the box, it's certainly possible by writing your own authorize attribute.

```cs
public class ConfigAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var allowedUsers = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CoolActionAllowedUsers"];
        var allowedUsersArray = allowedUsers.Split(',');

        if (httpContext.User.Identity != null && allowedUsersArray.Contains(httpContext.User.Identity.Name))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And to use the attribute:

```cs
[ConfigAuthorize]
public ActionResult CoolAction() {
    //...
}
```

In the code above when your authorization is performed in `AuthorizeCore`, the configuration value from `CoolActionAllowedUsers` will be pulled into memory and the currently authenticated user will be verified if they are in the list of allowed users.  If you make a change to your config file it won't be a problem; the application pool will automatically restart and the next time the code runs to read the config file your new value will be read.

I completely agree with @Shoe that roles should be used. Managing a list of users in your code is just a pain in the arse. In fact, at work, anytime I get a request for just one random user to have access to a page I always require a group to be setup.  However the code above could apply to a list of roles as well.

Comment: thanks for the answer, this actually answers my question.  Although I agree 100% with the recommendation Shoe presented as a best practice; what I often see here on Stackoverflow is a responders opinion overshadowing what a user is actually asking.  We all have the right to own own opinions but oftentimes there is a legitimate reason someone asks a question on how to do something.  That being said, I gave you both props for your respective answers.

Comment: My answer was to give what was needed, not necessarily what was wanted. The answer that fits better to the question of "How do I fit a square peg into a round hole?" is obviously "Don't use a square peg, use a round one" instead of "Get a saw, cut the peg, sand the peg, repaint it, then it should fit". This answer, certainly answers the question, though I don't see why it would ever be taken over simply using `Roles`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `Users` parameter use the `Roles` parameter.

```
[Authorize(Roles="CanExecuteActions")]
```

Now you can manage what users have access to your controller by giving them this role. Any user without the role can't execute any actions of the controller.

Comment: thanks for the response.  I already knew how to do that.  What I REALLY wanted to know is can I do it the way I asked in the question but I am going to give you props for answering and take it as a 'no, it can't be done'.

Comment: Yes the users parameter isn't really that useful or scalable. You will save a lot of headache in the long run with a special role.